# Multiple AsyncTask request handling

Tags: android, android-asynctask, baseadapter

In one of my project I need to call asyncTask in my getView method of custom adapter.
So ther is multiple asynctask request are in queue.

By default the asynctask work as first in first out.That is first request will process first then it will goes to next one. What i need is last in first out.

How can I handle asyncTask to work as mentioned above?

Also like to whether there is any method to get the count of pending asyncTask request.Searched a lot couldnt find a solution.

Comment: my app is to load animation drawable to image view so if there is lot of image the last image taking too much time load its animation drawable.So if i scrolled to last list item i need that one set first

Comment: Its depends on your `APIs` request call and dependency. Although you can call multiple `AsyncTask` in parallel using `asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)`)

Comment: where i have too add these lines of code

Comment: new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.thumbView).execute(detail.getPath()); 

this is how i am calling asyncTask now

Comment: If you have already the animated image (gif) with you, then use Glide...it works or you can use custom animation to the view downloaded too

Comment: its not gif its animation drawable created from video frames

Comment: you have a fixed number of `AsyncTask` or dynamic task.?

Comment: dynamic,almost solved my problem

Comment: @PiyushGupta how to handle if our asytask limit exceeds the maximum thread limit?? can we override the threadpoolclass?